# Sync Framework unnecessary upload

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, microsoft-sync-framework

I have a .NET application using the Microsoft sync framework to synchronise data between a SQL Server 2008 R2 server and a number of SQL Server CE clients.

The initial sync successfully downloads the data on the server, however the sync logging indicates that it then performs an upload of the unchanged data it just completed downloading. This is extending initial sync times greatly.

Extract from the SQL CE Logs below (this is the initial sync for one of the tables):

```
***** Client Provider Commit Transaction ****
Connecting to database: Data\Database.sdf
**** Client Provider Begin Transaction ****
----- Client Applying Changes from Server for Group "Staff" -----
----- Applying Deletes for Table Staff-----
Deletes Applied: 0
--- End Applying Deletes for Table Staff-----
----- Applying Upserts for Table Staff-----
----- Applying Inserts for Table Staff-----
Inserts Applied: 1
----- Applying Updates for Table Staff-----
Updates Applied: 0
--- End Applying Upserts for Table Staff---
Staff: Set ReceivedAnchor value: 1832
--- End Client Applying Changes from Server for Group "Staff" ---
```

This is the logs for when changes are uploaded back to the server incorrectly, i.e. flagged as being updated when nothing has changed.

```
SELECT ut.* FROM    (select ut0.* from [Staff] as ut0 where      (ut0.__sysTrackingContext <>
@CNTX OR ut0.__sysTrackingContext IS NULL)      AND ut0.__sysChangeTxBsn >= @LBSN    ) as ut  
LEFT OUTER JOIN   (select txcs0.* from __sysTxCommitSequence as txcs0) as txcsInsert  ON 
ut.__sysInsertTxBsn = txcsInsert.__sysTxBsn  LEFT OUTER JOIN   (select txcs0.* from     
__sysTxCommitSequence as txcs0) as txcsUpdate  ON ut.__sysChangeTxBsn = txcsUpdate.__sysTxBsn 
WHERE    COALESCE(txcsUpdate.__sysTxCsn, ut.__sysChangeTxBsn) > @LCSN AND COALESCE    
(txcsUpdate.__sysTxCsn, ut.__sysChangeTxBsn) <= @ECSN   AND   (COALESCE(txcsInsert.__sysTxCsn, 
ut.__sysInsertTxBsn) <= @LCSN OR    COALESCE(txcsInsert.__sysTxCsn, ut.__sysInsertTxBsn) IS NULL 
OR    ut.__sysInsertTxBsn IN (SELECT SyncBsn FROM __syncTransactions))
Parameter: @LCSN Value: 0
Parameter: @LBSN Value: 0
Parameter: @ECSN Value: 408
Parameter: @CNTX Value: 73c9795b-29e5-49c3-8a66-f99f667225d5
Update for row with PK: StaffId = 1
```

On the server side, the Tracking Current Version is fine during the initial sync and then is incremented at some point which i am assuming is due to the client thinking the downloaded records are new.

One thing that may be causing this is that Tracking is disabled to setup the SyncScopes and then enabled. This is done after the initial syncs.

Not sure if i have provided enough information to be useful. Happy to provide more.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue (well at least with a workable (not ideal) solution). Its a interesting design. There are three units involved in the sync. A server, central sync device and an edge device. The syncing occurs as follows:

1. central device performs a bidirectional sync to server
2. edge device performs a bidirectional sync to central device.

The server has 2008 R2 and the central and edge device are running SQL CE.

The central sync and edge device get their initial data from the server, however at that time they dont know what they will be. When the application is started their role is determined. Because we have to disable and re-enable tracking on the central and edge devices to allow the CE to CE sync (couldnt find any other way fomaking this work as it was throwing the exception above in my comment), it seems to mess with the CE to SQL 2008 sync which was presenting the issue outlined above, i.e. the data initially synced is retransmitted to the server. This was resolved by manually setting the sent anchor, however had the side effect of the CE to CE databases transmitting the initial data to one another, which then transmitted it back to the server.

The sync framework did see this as a conflict when trying to update and insert the rows, however despite trying to set conflict resolution rules via a number of ways it didnt resolve the issue. We then tried to wipe the data in the edge device before the database is provisioned so that it could obtain the latest data from the central device. This resolved the issue. As mentioned this is not ideal, however it is a workable solution.

If you have any thoughts on how to resolve this without needing to wipe the edge device that would be appreciated as it would be beneficial to have edge device sync setup without needing to reload all the data that was initially downloaded during the initial setup.

Cheers.

Comment: which provider are you using? you mentioned in your original post Sync Scopes so am assuming you're using the SqlCeSyncProvider/SqlSyncProvider/SyncOrchestrator combo. but then you mentioned setting an anchor. Anchors are used in the older SqlCeClientSyncProvider/DBServerSyncProvider/SyncAgent.

Comment: Hi JuneT, both are used. Unsure why (as it is an existing design). The Orchestrator is used for the CE to CE and the SyncAgent is used for the CE to SQL 2008 syncing. I suspect this is the root cause of the problem I am facing, however I do not have enough knowledge in this area to know for sure, I would presume it was implemented for a good reason?

Comment: that explains it. these two different combos workd differently and you can't mix and match. SqlCeSyncProvider/SqlSyncProvider/SyncOrchestrator alone should do the trick. you are disabling and enabling change tracking to the CE DBs to get them to sync. But this resets the change tracking that works with CE synching to SQL Server. Not sure why you would want to do it this way not unless you don't want custom change tracking on SQL Server and only use the built-in SQL Change Tracking. the SyncOrchestrator approach would have been the most appropriate for your scenario.

Comment: Thanks JuneT. Will look at changing it to use only one type of provider.

Answer (score 0):

how are you doing the initial sync? if you're doing it without using Sync Framework or when Tracking is disabled, then Sync Framework has no idea about the what was initially synched.

Comment: Hi JuneT, as far as I am aware Sync Framework is being used to perform the initial sync. The is code that disables tracking on the database and then provisions it, which i believe is causing the issue. When this code is commented out, the problem is removed, however CE to CE syncs do not work. I belive this is due to the databases being copied initially as the following exception is received during CE to CE syncs ( A column named '__sysTrackingContext' already belongs to this DataTable.), however implementing code that performs a snapshot does not assist in resolving the issue.

Comment: when you disable change tracking, then you wipe out the existing change tracking information. when you re-enable it, you're "re-creating" the change tracking metadata. How are you creating the SQL CE snapshots?